# Can rootkits and malwares affect a live ubuntu usb with no peristence?

Tags: ubuntu, liveusb, rootkit

Can rootkits and malwares affect a live ubuntu usb with no peristence ? Can any malware possibly persist and affect all the sessions ? Also, can it affect current session if it cannot persist ? I am asking this because in live use the root user does not require any password(at least by default). I am using ubuntu 14.04 desktop, if that matters.

Comment: Yes; Its possible a live environment could infect the MBR of a system disk. But like all infections you would have to ignore all security precautions in order to be infected with something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few viruses, that can infect MBR or BIOS, eg.:

http://www.webroot.com/blog/2011/09/13/mebromi-the-first-bios-rootkit-in-the-wild/
https://blogs.mcafee.com/mcafee-labs/bioskits-join-ranks-of-stealth-malware

Note that MBR virus can possibly affect you even if you use Live CD, if you boot from GRUB and manually choose to redirect booting process to Live CD.

However, most of such viruses run only on Windows platforms, and you can't catch such virus using Ubuntu. So, the real question is: are your MBR and BIOS are clean now?

Comment: if you boot from GRUB => if you boot from GRUB on infected drive